# Is it OK to place methods like hasSomething() or isSomething in entities?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

We always use entities in Symfony2 as plain PHP objects with setters and getters only. But if we have collection inside an entity it may be useful to place there methods, like hasSomeProperty($name) or isSomething($someType). For example:

```
class User
{
    /** @var ArrayCollection */
    private $friends;

    public function hasFriend($name)
    {
         foreach ($this->friends as $friend) {
             if ($friend->getName() === $name) {
                 return true;
             }
         }

         return false;
    }
}
```

From one point of view this method contains logic, which shouldn't be placed in entities. But such logic relates ONLY to this entity, so according to the law of Demeter, entity is the right place to write it. What are your thoughts about it?

Comment: You can put custom functions at the end of your entity class.

Comment: This question, although a good one, is too heavily opinion based too be a correct StackOverflow question. Apart from that: I think it's perfectly fine to have hassers/issers in your entity

Comment: @WouterJ, fully agree with you, probably there no one correct answer. But I'm interested to hear conventions, that people use in their projects, because we have debates about it in our team.

Comment: @WouterJ while this question may well be a bit opinion based it has a strong educational value for new symfonians. The danger of exposing sensible information just for the external calculation of `hasX()` or `isX()` ... plus maybe creating a large number of `getY()`, `getZ()`, ... methods can't be denied. I even think it can be considered a *best-practice* to keep these methods inside entitites.

Answer (score 5):

It's definitely okay and a good practice to add these `hasX()` or `isX()` methods to your entities and I personally think it's the correct place to put them.

The **main argument** to keep these methods inside your entity is that
you have access to `private` and `protected` properties to calculate the result of `hasX()` or `isX()`.

Otherwise - putting reflection aside - you'd need to expose (maybe sensible) information to the public API by creating a getter function for a property that doesn't serve any other purpose.

You could even end up adding a huge amount of getter functions that ... only serve the purpose to calculate the result externally.

You can see an example in FOSUserBundle's `Model\User` class. **([Code](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php#L305))**